# Can I group a list of objects based on an attribute, and pass these new lists into a method one at a time within a stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

Basically have a list of objects of type `Obj`, each with a specific attribute field on them that share values.

`[ Obj1, Obj3, Obj2, Obj4, ... , Obj500 ]`.

`Obj1.value = a`
`Obj2.value = b`
`Obj3.value = a`
`Obj4.value = b`, etc.

Can I group these objects into their own lists, and pass these lists into a function one at a time all in the same stream? Just `[Obj1, Obj3], [Obj2, Obj4]`, and then each of these lists into a function?

Comment: did you take a look at `collectingAndThen`?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not directly within the stream, but it’s in the same method chain (not tested):

```
objList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(obj -> obj.value))
        .values()
        .forEach(this::function);
```

This is assuming that `function` is a non-static method in the class where you are doing the stream operation. Otherwise modify the last line to your situation, for example `.forEach(YourClass::someStaticMethod);`. It is also assuming that you don’t need to pick up any return value from that method call.

The `groupingBy` operation in the stream pipeline produces a `Map` where `a` and `b` are keys and `[Obj1, Obj3]` and `[Obj2, Obj4]` are the values. So I take out the collection of values. Since a `Collection` is always an `Iterable` I can then use `Iterable.forEach` for passing each list to the function (it’s not a new stream operation).